# Chromium 32.0.1700.19 cannot display Chinese title

Tags: gentoo, chrome

My system is Gentoo 64bit, Chromium 32.0.1700.19. With Chromium 31, it was able to display Chinese in the title correctly. But since version 32, Chinese are displayed as blank in the title, while the Chinese in the webpage can be displayed correctly.

Some old Chromium bugs says font configuration could cause this problem. But Chromium does not have a log, I cannot find which font configuration caused this problem. Any idea?

Comment: it also happens to my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, Chromium 34

Comment: it happens if I use Xubuntu. But in Unity it does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the discussions about this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316723&q=chinese%20title&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), I found the issue is caused by the font `85-wqy-bitmapsong`, which is installed by package `wqy-bitmapfont`

Answer (score 2):

I tested the Chinese Wikipedia with both 32.0.1687.2 and 33.0.1711.3 and neither of them had any problem displaying the title.
Btw, chromium does have a log. 
Try starting chromium from terminal emulator as such:

```
chromium --enable-logging --v=1 https://zh.wikipedia.org/
```

Then check, `~/.config/chromium/chrome_debug.log`.

Comment: OK, I just tried. No complain about font in the log...